# How to select the most important rows per assigned priority?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to convert a df where an id is duplicated convert it to one row for id and take the value from a list of priority.

```
-----------
id | value
-----------
1     MV1
1     MV2
2     VPV
2    Others
```

And the priority list is:

1. "MV1"
2. "MV2"
3. "VPV"
4. "Others"

so the output should be:

```
-----------
id | value
-----------
1     MV1
2     VPV
```

I tried to create a column and assigning a numerical value (mv1->1 mv2->2) and sorting it with a window function to take the first row only but I don't think it's a great solution.

What would be the optimal way to do it?

I'm using scala as language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick I'd use would be to use `join` between the input dataset and the priorities (ranked).

```
val priorities = Seq(
  "MV1",
  "MV2",
  "VPV",
  "Others").zipWithIndex.toDF("name", "rank")

val ids = Seq(
  (1, "MV1"),
  (1, "MV2"),
  (2, "VPV"),
  (2, "Others")).toDF("id", "priority")

val mins = ids
  .join(priorities)
  .where($"priority" === $"name")
  .groupBy("id")
  .agg(min("rank") as "min")
val q = mins.join(priorities).where($"min" === $"rank").select("id", "name")
```

The result seems to match the expectations.

```
scala> q.show
+---+----+
| id|name|
+---+----+
|  1| MV1|
|  2| VPV|
+---+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved it was using `withColumn`, `row_number` and `window` functions and it turned out to be quite simple. Works the same way as the other answer posted here but in a more optimized way, I guess.

```
    val result = inputDF
    .withColumn("row_number", row_number.over(Window.partitionBy($"id").orderBy($"id")))
    .where($"row_number" === 1)
    .drop("row_number")
```

This way you are setting the priorities by id and then selecting the first one of each of them with the `orderBy` clause.

Clean and efficient :)